# How to normalize a range in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the following object data in each row:

```
1-10,
11-20,
21-30,
31-40,
```

and so on.

I need to normalize each range.  I can't figure out how to separate each number.  Once I get them separated I can convert them to int64 and use the following formula to get ranges notmalized and have a new coum with the results:

```
normalized_df=(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
```

but i need to capture the numbers separately to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it like so:

```
df["min_val"] = df.nums.str.split("-").apply(lambda x:x[0])
df["max_val"] = df.nums.str.split("-").apply(lambda x:x[1])
```